# using SVM to predict traffic volume

Tags: regression, svm, libsvm, prediction, traffic

I used **SVM** to **predict traffic volume data**, using the tool **libSVM**.
Input is the data in the moment t-2, t-1 and t; the output is the data in moment t+1.
The param is below:

```
    param.svm_type = svm_parameter.NU_SVR;
    param.kernel_type = svm_parameter.RBF;
    param.cache_size = 100;
    param.eps = 0.00001;
    param.C = 1.9;
    param.nu = 0.5;
```

But the predict value is **a constant number**, I don't know what is the problem.
Thanks.